# Template is missing for the page when form is submitted using magnolia

Tags: magnolia

This is the template 
enter image description here

```
@Controller
@Template(title = "Main", id = "sampleModule:pages/main")
public class MainTemplate {
@Area("header")
@Controller
@AvailableComponentClasses()
public static class Header {

    @RequestMapping("/mainTemplate/header")
    public String render() {
        return "pages/headerArea.jsp";
    }
}

@Area("main")
@Controller
@AvailableComponentClasses({LoginFormComponent.class} )
public static class MainArea {

    @RequestMapping("/mainTemplate/home")
    public String render() {
        return "pages/mainArea.jsp";
    }
}

/**
 * footer area.
 */
@Area("footer")
@Controller
@AvailableComponentClasses()
public static class Footer {

    @RequestMapping("/mainTemplate/footer")
    public String render() {
        return "pages/footerArea.jsp";
    }
}
```

}

Here the form component i have added in the main area

```
@Controller
@Template(title = "Login Form", id = sampleModule:components/login")
public class LoginFormComponent {
@Autowired
private LoginServiceImpl loginServiceImpl;
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String render(@ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm,HttpServletRequest request) {
   return "components/loginForm.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String rendering( @ModelAttribute("loginForm") @Valid LoginForm loginForm,BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request) {

      new LoginFormValidator().validate(loginForm, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "components/loginForm.jsp";
        }

      return "components/loginSucess.jsp";
 }
```

before form submission that is when get method is called the login page is rendering along with the template.

when click on submit, that is submitting the form then only that jsp is rendering with out template and the error messages are displaying.

How to over come that, can any one please suggest me?

Here is some screen shots below

[image: Getting the page]

[image: after form submission]

Comment: Looks like the same question posted [here][1], see [my answer][2] there.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29530641/150333
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29695343/150333